# How to define "node type" in Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, gatsby, jamstack

In [Gatsby tutorial part 6](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-6), you can find multiple mentions of "node type" :

> According to the API, you need to decide on two things before creating a collection route:
>
> - Which type of node to create pages from.
> - Which field from that node type to use in the URL.

> To create a new collection route, you name your file `{nodeType.field}.js`, where `nodeType` is the type of node you want to create pages from, and `field` is the data field from that node type that you want to use in the URL for that page.

My aim would be to create a page tree like :

- `index.tsx`
- `blog/{article.slug}.tsx`
- `projects/{project.slug}.tsx`
- `tags/{tag.id}.tsx`

All of *articles*, *projects* and *tags* would be MDX files but queried on specific location, or frontmatter prop.

But **I don't know how to create named node type** that I should use like `mdx` in `{mdx.slug}.js`.

I even tried to add an instance of `gatsby-source-filesystem` with a `name` to use as type but it didn't work :

```js
plugins: [
  // ...
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
    options: {
      path: `${__dirname}/_data`,
      name: "instances",
      __key: 'instances'
    }
  },
  "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-6/#create-new-routes-dynamically-with-gatsbys-file-system-route-api):

> `gatsby-plugin-mdx` automatically adds a `slug` field to each MDX
> node, which contains a string of the filename for the `.mdx` file
> (with the `.mdx` extension removed). You can see the `slug` field’s
> value for each MDX node in GraphiQL. If you run the following query:

So you just need to use [`gatsby-plugin-mdx`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/) to create an slug based on the filename:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-page-creator",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  ],
}
```

*Note: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` may be required depending on your desired folder structure/source*

Once you've set properly your folder structure, your slug field `will` be available (because the node will be inferred from the plugins and accessible by GraphQL) so you will be able to create pages using the Filesystem Route API like `blog/{article.slug}.tsx`.

Applied to your code this means that you only need to use `/pages/blog/{mdx.slug}.js`.

According to what you said, you will need to create several instances of `gatsby-source-filesystem` to create multiple sources.

Since your `index.tsx` won't be dynamically created, you can just directly create it under `/pages` folder.

Comment: Hello, my question is to know how to define new set of nodes like `mdx`. You took the example of `article.slug`, so how do I define the `article` group ?

Comment: `gatsby-source-filesystem` has a `name` attribute where the node name is defined. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx-source-name/

Answer (score -1):

I think you actually call the filename `{mdx.slug}.js` as in `src/pages/{mdx.slug}.js`.
It IS a way to tell gatsy that this file will be used for dynamic `mdx.slug`.

Comment: Yes, but `mdx` is considered a node type, which is automatically created w/ both gatsby *filesystem* and *mdx* plugin.